# Pandas CSV: csv to orderedDict

Tags: python, pandas, csv

What is the best way to save ordered dictionary to csv, load the csv file into ordered dictionary of same format, edit them and save them back.

I save my data originally as follows:

```
gifs_info_list=[]
gifs_info_list.append(OrderedDict([('ID','aswd'),('class','c1'),('mu',gif["parameters"]["mu"]),('sigma','23'), ('tags', [u'movies', u'hitler']),('flag1',False),('flag2',False),('flag3',False)]))
```

here is how I am doing orderedDict2CSV

```
def list_to_csv(mlist, fname):
    '''
    double check this method => where is the header added to the csv?
    Arguments
        mlist: A list of orderedDict objects.
        fname:
    '''
    df = pd.DataFrame(mlist)
    df.to_csv(fname, sep='\t')
```

This saves the data to csv, as follows:

```
  ID    class   mu  sigma   tags    flag1 flag2 flag3
0   fdex    c1  39.8348689258   2.49703182691   [u'movies', u'hitler']  False   False   False
2   11AE    c2  38.7252538197   2.23352853216   [u'movie', u'mark millar']  False   False   False
3   p9ut    c1  37.775785901    2.33519338409   []  False   False   False
```

I need to write CSV2OrderedDict that would load the data from the csv into a list of orderedDicts of the same format as it was created. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need `csv`? Is not possible save to json?

Comment: yes I do need csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def csv_to_list(fname):
    df = pd.from_csv(fname, index_col=0)
    return [OrderedDict(row[1]) for row in df.iterrows()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read `csv` file using `pd.read_csv` function. Then you can iterate over rows of `DataFrame` using `iterrows()` method, in each iteration create `OrderedDict` and append it to list.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep="\t", index_col=0)
dicts = list()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    d = OrderedDict(zip(row.index.tolist(),
                        row.tolist()))
    dicts.append(d)
```

The output will be:

```
>>> dicts

[OrderedDict([('ID', 'fdex'),
              ('class', 'c1'),
              ('mu', 39.8348689258),
              ('sigma', 2.49703182691),
              ('tags', "[u'movies', u'hitler']"),
              ('flag1', False),
              ('flag2', False),
              ('flag3', False)]),
 OrderedDict([('ID', '11AE'),
              ('class', 'c2'),
              ('mu', 38.7252538197),
              ('sigma', 2.23352853216),
              ('tags', "[u'movie', u'mark millar']"),
              ('flag1', False),
              ('flag2', False),
              ('flag3', False)]),
 OrderedDict([('ID', 'p9ut'),
              ('class', 'c1'),
              ('mu', 37.775785901),
              ('sigma', 2.33519338409),
              ('tags', '[]'),
              ('flag1', False),
              ('flag2', False),
              ('flag3', False)])]
```

EDIT: `tags` will be a string, not a list. If you want to convert it to list use

```
import ast
df['tags'] = df['tags'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```